# How would I read every line of a text file and set each line as a separate string?

Tags: c#, winforms

I've got this code:

> ```
>       List<string[]> list = File.ReadLines(@"bin\save.dat")
>                                 .Select(r => r.TrimEnd('#').Split(','))
>                                 .ToList();
>
>       Console.WriteLine(File.ReadLines(@"bin\save.dat"));
> ```

But it keeps returning **System.IO.ReadLinesIterator**

I've tried other things on the forum but nothing has worked for me.

Comment: Have you looked through the rest of the methods available in the File class, such as `ReadAllLines()`?

Comment: _"it keeps returning System.IO.ReadLinesIterator"_ -- because that's the name of the type of the object, and the object doesn't override `ToString()`. You don't want to print the object itself, you want to print its contents. See duplicates for the explanation of what's going on and for examples of how to use `ReadLines()` correctly.

Answer (score 0):

To display each line to the console, one solution would be to change

```
Console.WriteLine(File.ReadLines(@"bin\save.dat"));
```

to

```
foreach (var line in File.ReadLines(@"bin\save.dat"))
    Console.WriteLine(line);
```

Answer (score 0):

try to use StreamReader :

```
System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(@"bin\save.dat");
```

and then if you want to get all lines ,you can loop till the end of file:

```
string line;
     while((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
{
  //do something with line
}
```

Comment: StreamReader implements `IDisposable`, and so should be disposed of properly.